# How to select value based on between Range in SQL?

Tags: sql

I need to get the Result value based on given Input from the following table.

```
Gender |MinAge |MaxAge | Result
-------------------------------
C        0      25       0.11
M        0      25       1.12
M        26     30       2.25
M        31     35       1.20 
M        36     40       3.58
F        0      25       1.25
F        26     30       2.25
F        31     35       1.20
F        36     40       2.02

Input values 1 
***************
Gender - M
Age    - 28

Expected Output 
---------------
2.25


Input Values 2
***************
Gender - F
Age    - 32

Expected Output
----------------

1.20
```

I try with Between condition but unable to find solution. I'm new to SQL. Please tell me how to write query for above condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
*
from
your_table
where Gender = 'M'
and 28 between MinAge and MaxAge
```